# Git Describe NPM not providing Tag information

Tags: node.js, git, npm, git-describe

I am trying [Git-Describe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-describe) npm package to retrieve hash information and tag to append to my application later.

I have following the instruction that are provided in the [Git describe npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-describe). The script worked well but the tag information is retrieved as null here. Also I have added few tags in the local and my remote git.

I am able to retrieve all the tag information using `git tag -l`

The below is the script that I was trying to run.

```
const {gitDescribe, gitDescribeSync} = require('git-describe');
 
// Another example: working directory, use 16 character commit hash abbreviation
const gitInfo = gitDescribeSync({
    customArguments: ['--abbrev=16']
});
 
// Asynchronous with promise
gitDescribe(__dirname)
    .then((gitInfo) => console.dir(gitInfo))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
 
// Asynchronous with node-style callback
gitDescribe(__dirname, (err, gitInfo) => {
    if (err)
        return console.error(err);
    console.dir(gitInfo);
});
```

node version.js

Output is:

```
{
  dirty: true,
  raw: 'f8f7e57e-dirty',
  hash: 'f8f7e57e',
  distance: null,
  tag: null,
  semver: null,
  suffix: 'f8f7e57e-dirty',
  semverString: null,
  toString: [Function]
}
```

Here the tag info are coming with null. But the hash string is correct. (Git log output).

```
commit **f8f7e57e**713b71b0f9d3181c0d19ffd (HEAD -> PF223095_US1834348_ui_gitcommit, tag: r9.0.6, origin/PF223095_US1834348_ui_gitcommit, mastere)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like by default git-describe only tracks versions that start with `v` so something like `v1.0.0` works and `1.0.0` fails.

Answer (score 0):

As @zxiiro said, the [default behaviour](https://github.com/tvdstaaij/node-git-describe#options) is to look for tags starting with `v` followed by a digit (`v0.9`, `v2.3-dev`).

You can specify your own regex with the match option, this example will match tags starting with a digit (`0.9`, `2.3-dev`, `99-luft-balloons`)

```
const gitInfo = gitDescribeSync({match: '[0-9]*'});
```